# Join data from two different arrays if specific fields are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays.

**exam:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Avaliação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Avaliação de Recuperação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    }
]
```

**exam_score:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "score": "0.00",
        "exam_id": 1
    }
]
```

I need to check if the exam_id field of the second array is equal to some id of the first array.

I'm doing it as follows:

```
const merged = exams.map((e) => ({
  ...e,
  exam_score: { ...exam_score.some(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
}));
```

However, I get the error:

```
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor
```

Is this the correct way to perform this procedure? Why is this error happening?

***Edit:***

I believe that the error is happening because the data that I need to show is within that "dataValues", how do I show the data that is there?

Function adjusted according to the suggestions:

```
const merged = exams.map((e) => ({
  ...e.dataValues,
  exam_score: { ...exam_score.find(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
}));
```

Console.log:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Avaliação - Procedimento em Serras',
    description: 'Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação.',
    exam_score: {
      dataValues: [Object],
      _previousDataValues: [Object],
      _changed: {},
      _modelOptions: [Object],
      _options: [Object],
      isNewRecord: false
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Avaliação de Recuperação - Procedimento em Serras',
    description: 'Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação.',
    exam_score: {}
  }
]
```

The error happens when I use `return.json({merged})` ou `return.json(merged)`.

Comment: What is `return.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)  which return `true` or `false` if the element exist. You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for an element and returns the element if exists.

```js
const exam = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Avaliação - Procedimento em Serras",
    description: "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação.",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Avaliação de Recuperação - Procedimento em Serras",
    description: "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação.",
  },
];

const exam_score = [
  {
    id: 4,
    score: "0.00",
    exam_id: 1,
  },
];

const merged = exam.map((e) => ({
  ...e,
  exam_score: { ...exam_score.find(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
}));

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: I edited the question. I believe that my problem, in addition to the way I searched for the information, is because I am returning a json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` and `map` methods of arrays to match the values from the two arrays.

If you want the matching value of the `exam_score` array then you can write:

```
exam_score.filter((e) => {
    return exam.map((q) => q.id === e.exam_id)
})
```

If you want the matching value of the `exam` array then you can use:

```
exam_score.map((e) => {
    return exam.filter((q) => q.id === e.exam_id)
})
```

Comment: `filter` returns array. So Fred need to access with array index like `exam_score: { ...exam_score.filter(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id)[0] },`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the information you have put in is enough to understand why you're getting this error. It might probably because you are trying to use `console.log` with `JSON.stringify` for an object which references itself.

However, I see that the issue is in this line,

```js
exam_score: { ...exam_score.some(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
```

where you should use `find` method instead of `some`. Try this

```js
exam_score: { ...exam_score.find(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
```

Comment: I edited the question, I believe you will understand better.